# Rails + Devise: Disable Password Login (only oauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am developing an app which for now needs to have registrations/password logins disabled, but they may be used in the future. Currently, it only allows logins/registrations via an oauth flow, which is setup using omniauth.

To disable registrations I removed :registerable from my User model and skipped registrations routes, but I am wondering what is the proper way to do the same thing for logins as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this not what you're trying to do? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#using-omniauth-without-other-authentications

Comment: @Alex oh i missed that! looks good, I will try it out now